# What is the purpose of delete $get prop in angular Provider?

Tags: angularjs

I saw a piece of code about Angular's Provider like below:

```js
angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme')
    .provider('baConfig', configProvider);

  /** @ngInject */
  function configProvider() {
    var conf = {
      theme: {
        blur: false
      }
    };

    conf.changeTheme = function(theme) {
      angular.merge(conf.theme, theme)
    };

    conf.$get = function () {
      // what does this code meaning? why delete $get?
      delete conf.$get;
      return conf;
    };
    return conf;
  }
```

But i don't know the `delete conf.$get` to mean what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the author of this provider thought it was a good idea to return the provider itself from the $get method. So, the service created by the provider is the provider itself.

Since $get should obviously not be part of the methods of the service, but only of the methods of the provider, he/she removed the $get method after $get has been called by angular to create the service instance.

I wouldn't use that code as a good example of how to create a service using a provider. Just use a different object for the provider and the service.